# task Synchronization in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

one function can be triggered by two events but dont let it trigger by second event after it already occured by one event for example a function creates a box and it can be done by 2 methods

1. press enter
2. focus out

so once the box is created dont let it create by the other event.(please tell multiple ways to do it).

```
<textarea onfocusout="createFolder()>
or
$("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    // $('textarea').replaceWith('<p class="text-center bd-title">' + $("textarea").val() + '</p>')
           createFolder();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can maintain a flag

```
let isFolderCreated = false;
$("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    if (!isFolderCreated && (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey)) {
           isFolderCreated = true;
           createFolder();
      }
});
```

all its doing here is checking if the folder is not created and creating the folder

Comment: its a good approach but i want something more simple flags, can get pretty hard to manage especially when functionality is scaled.

Comment: one way or another there needs to be check if the folder is created. let it be via flags or by a function.